# Commandline global proxy program?

Tags: command-line, proxy

I'm living in China, and lots of web service is not available or stable here like Github/Bitbucket/Imgur, When I'm using `wget`, `git` or some other commandline tools, I need using a proxy.

Is there any tool to globally wrap socket connection in one terminal, so I don't need to memorize all the separate method for each commandline tools? I know there is some tools which can wrap std socket library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one, it is `proxychain`: https://github.com/haad/proxychains

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you look at [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/) that allows you to forward all connections to a SOCKS4 proxy, without changing your command lines; `tsocks on` is possibly the command you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are some scripts which uses `redsocks` to create transparent proxy. Check it out https://github.com/dilawar/Transparent-Proxy .